# AVPlayer seekToTime: doesn't use buffer

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, http-streaming

I am developing an application for playing video using **HTTP Live Streaming** technology.
For this I use **AVPlayer** which init as follows:

`[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:VIDEO_URL]];`

Then I check the state of the buffer using `self.player.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges` and display this range on my custom view.

The problem is that when rewinding in an area that is loaded by `[self.player seekToTime:timeToSeek
                toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero
                 toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];`, loads the video starts just as if it was not in the buffer.

Comment: Running on device helped

Comment: Hey Pavel - did you figure this out? I'm running into this issue now. I'm testing on a physical device. Did testing on a device remove the issue for you?

Comment: no need to seek, when you use live streaming.. you have to play current stream only right?

Comment: @AshishKakkad - I'm streaming 3/4 minute videos to a device. My problem is that when a user seeks somewhere in the video that they are streaming, the buffer gets cleared.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, my answer assumes that you are using HTTP Live Streaming for a static m3u8 list, otherwise seeking within the video will not make much sense.

### Possible Cause

HTTP Live Streaming uses an m3u style playlist which embeds sub playlists.
Each sub-playlist shows different video quality and the AVPlayer chooses which one to use according to the network speed.

But, according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW17), when the player initially starts playing it first chooses the first sub-playlist and only after a couple of ts files were played it chooses the appropriate sub-playlist as described above.

So it could be that when you seek to a certain time, the player first tries to play the first sub-list which is not cached.

### Suggested Solution

Try the following:

1. Change the m3u8 stream to have only one sub-stream.
2. Use a value other than kCMTimeZero for the tolerance, i.e.`CMTimeMake(30, 60)`
3. Monitor the network calls to see what exactly it is that the player downloads and when, you could use [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for example.

Comment: If we go with 1st solution then I guess Apple will reject the app. As streaming, the sub-stream will kill the purpose of using HLS videos

Answer (score 1):

Try to use sample code [StitchedStreamPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092) provided in iOS Developer's library for your answer..